# Migrating / Synchronising couchbase buckets between dev sandboxes

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I'm relatively new to **Couchbase** (and nosql) so maybe I'm missing something obvious but what I'd like to be able to do is automate building a new environment as much as possible.

With MySql I can relatively easily create `.sql` files and use them to both create the table structures as well as do the appropriate inserts to add all base reference data that I want loaded into a new environment. What's the best way to do something similar in Couchbase? Are there any tools (open source or otherwise) that might help with this?

My initial thought was to use the client API to "get" all the bucket data into .JSON files and then on the other end use another script to "put" it back into the bucket. Not sure this is the most elegant way of moving the data but it also does nothing about the moving the "schema". Yes I know schema might be seen as a dirty word in nosql but what I mean is ideally I'd like to use reflection on the source environment and identify all the buckets and views and then be able to recreate these on the targe environment.

Comment: Perhaps you could use cb_transfer? See http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbtransfer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt Couchbase 'cbbackup' and 'cbrestore' commands through the CLI.

They will copy Data, and views etc. to a specified env.

The docs can be found here:

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbbackup.html

I hope this helps!

**Robin J.**

Comment: Seems like a sensible approach. I'm struggling at the moment as I can't get the command to stop giving me a `[Errno 61] Connection refused` error. I've checked that the username and password are the same that work on the web interface. Any ideas?

Comment: Btw, my connection error was just due to a boneheaded mistake ... I used the wrong port for the CLI call. Oops.

Answer (score 1):

So in addition to the cbbackup and cbtransfer ( http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-cmdline-cbtransfer.html ) tools you can also depending of the volume use the XDCR (Cross Data Center Replication) in a single direction (from your production to development environment).

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-admin-tasks-xdcr.html

Comment: I was wondering if I should look at that option. For now I'm going to stick to the cbbackup/cbtransfer but I'll make a mental note to come back to this approach in 6 months.